# How del function is executed in this Program ? How del function is executed in this Program ?How del function is executed in this Program?

Tags: java, linked-list

In this linked list program how del function work I don't understand especially in the while condition can someone explain it

Node is linklist

```
class newjava {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Node head= new Node(10);
        head.next = new Node(20);
        head.next.next = new Node(30);
        head.next.next.next = new Node(40);
        del(head);
        printf(head);
    }
    
    static Node del(Node head) {
        if(head==null)   // 
        return null;
        if(head.next==null) return null;   
    
        Node curr = head;
        while(curr.next.next != null)
        curr=curr.next;
        curr.next=null;
        return head;
    
    }
    
    static void printf(Node head)
    {
        while(head!=null) {
            System.out.println(head.data);
            head=head.next;
             
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Fix your title.

Comment: Fix the format of your code, e.g. the code inside the `while` loop you're asking about should be indented.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
There are only two points you need to know for understanding the code.

**Point 1.**
When **curr.next.next == null**, the curr.next will be the tail node in the list.

So that why the following code deletes the tail node.

```
curr.next=null;
```

**Point 2.**
The purpose of this code is to find the first current node that satisfy some condition.

```
Node curr = head;
while(curr.next.next != null) {
  curr=curr.next;
}
```

And the condition is "**curr.next.next == null**".

**Conclusion.**

The purpose of point two is to find the previous node of the tail node and set it to the variable **curr**.

So **curr.next** is the tail node and we delete it. (point one)